# Agrupar registro de todo un mes por hora ignorando el dia

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy intentando agrupar todas registros de un mes por hora, ignorando el dia en que sucedieron.
Tengo un indice DateTime como el siguiente:

```
2020-03-02 07:28:20
2020-03-02 07:30:20
2020-03-02 07:32:20
2020-03-02 07:32:40
       .
       .
2020-03-30 07:32:40
2020-03-02 07:33:53
```

y logre agruparlo por mes asi y por hora, por separado:

```
periodo = df.index.to_period("M")
grupo = pd.Grouper(level = 0, freq = 'H')
df.groupby([periodo,grupo]).count()
```

resultado del indice:

```
[('2020-03', '2020-03-02 07:00:00'),
 ('2020-03', '2020-03-02 08:00:00'),
 ('2020-03', '2020-03-02 09:00:00'),
              .
              .
 ('2020-03', '2020-03-30 09:00:00')]
```

Tambien al hacer:

```
df.groupby([periodo, df.index.time]).count()
```

Me devuelve las horas sin agrupar, entonces tengo un 1 nivel de mes, y el segundo con las horas, minutos y segundos sin agrupar.

Intente tambien de hacer un split en la hora del primer DateTime:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'Hora', freq = 'H'))
```

Pero al intentar agruparlo me devuelve:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

Ya no se que hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si al agrupar tomas solo la hora en vez del tiempo completo

```py
periodo = df.index.to_period("M")
df.groupby([periodo, df.index.hour]).count()
```

Comment: Hermoso! me acabas de resolver la vida. Siempre que estas trabado es la solcuion mas sencilla. Muchas gracias!!